# Unexpected output when reading a file in python

Tags: python, editor

I'm making a little text editor but I'm having difficulty saving output. First, someone could only have one line of text. Now, they can technically have several, but everything is still saved to the file in one line, and in a weird order. Here is my code so far:

```
def typer():
    while True:
        typercmd = input("    ")
        if typercmd == ("|"):
            break
        typercmd2 = input("    ")
        if typercmd2 == ("|"):
            break
        typercmd3 = input("    ")
        if typercmd3 == ("|"):
            break
        typercmd4 = input("    ")
        if typercmd4 == ("|"):
            break
    saveAs = input("Save file as: ")
    with open(saveAs, 'a') as f:
        f.write(typercmd)
        f.write(typercmd2)
        f.write(typercmd3)
        f.write(typercmd4)
```

Here's what I use to open the text:

```
def fopen():
    file = input("Open: ")
    print("")
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            print(line)
    print("")
```

Here's an example of what's happening:
I wrote four individual lines of text (they were `Test`, `Chicken`, `Word`, and `Variety`. I then used `|` on a fifth line to end typing. When I saved it and opened the file, it read:

`|ChickenWordVariety`

Something is clearly wrong, but I can't for the life of me figure it out (I'm also fairly new to python). Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your loop reads input four times—if you enter five lines, then the fifth line is actually the first input to the second pass through the loop.

Comment: Can you go back and fix the indentations in the code block? It helps us sort out program flow without guessing what you meant.

Comment: Can't reproduce... using your input I got a file called `|` containing `TestChickenWordVariety`. To debug, you could change `input(" ")` to `input("1 ")`, `input("2 ")`, etc... to see where you are in the editing stream.

Comment: As an aside, when updating your code block I noticed it mixed tabs and spaces. That can be very dangerous with python because indents that look right to you may look wrong to python. Stick with spaces!